# Undefined reference to leveldb when compiling Caffe

Tags: c++, cmake, undefined-reference, caffe, leveldb

My os is ubuntu15.10. When I using CMake to compile Caffe I got those error:

```
[ 95%] Built target train_net
Scanning dependencies of target classification
../lib/libcaffe.so： undefined reference to ‘leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&,   std::string const&, leveldb::DB**)’
../lib/libcaffe.so： undefined reference to ‘leveldb::Status::ToString() const’
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/build.make:126: recipe for target 'tools/caffe' failed
make[2]: *** [tools/caffe] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:406: recipe for target 'tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all] Error 2
```

I had installed libleveldb-dev yet.

And if I make USE_LEVELDB "Build with levelDB" become OFF in CMakeLists, compile would succeed, but the examples can't be run.

Answer (score 2):

Ok... 2 hours ago I fixed this problem by myself. I give up using CMake and made some changes in *makefile.configure* :

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/include /home/vic/leveldb/include/leveldb /opt/OpenBLAS/include
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /home/vic/leveldb /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial /opt/OpenBLAS/lib
```

I just add a series of addresses of libraries which I thought may be. 
 And finally I successfully compile Caffe by *make all* with levelDB and successfully run mnist. She may really can't find the libraries if they were not at the same place as earlier versions.